# Why are there $3$ solutions to $x^a = a^x$?

Tags: graphing-functions

Consider the equation, $x^a = a^x$.

If a is of the form $1.6 + 0.4k$, where $k$ is a natural number, then the equation has $3$ solutions.
I checked them until $k = 1000$, but was unable to find a reason for this.
Is there any plausible explanation for this? If yes, what is it? if not, why?

The possible duplicate question doesn't explain why there are 3 solutions for this particular form!

Thanks,
John.

Comment: I am understanding that for each integer $k$, you are fixing the value of $a$ and solving for $x$, am I correct?

Comment: @Krishnarjun , yes, that is what I am doing.

Comment: When k=1, the equation only has 2 real solutions.

Comment: @CristhianPardo, There are 3 real solutions when k = 1, (x = 2,4,and a negative value).

Comment: @Krishnarjun, Yes I got negative solutions as well, I tried rough sketching for few integral values of (a) and later graphed them on Desmos.

Comment: Does there exist a negative solution for non integral values of $a$?

Comment: @Krishnarjun, Yes there are 3 solutions for non integral values of a either, you can check it for yourself, here . :
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fhkmhptwxw

Answer (score 1):

**The two positive solutions**

On $x>0$, the value of $\frac{\ln x}{x}$ is monotonic increasing from $-\infty$ to  $\frac{1}{e}$ and then monotonic decreasing, tending to $0$.

Therefore, for $a>1$ and $a\ne e$, the horizontal line $y=\frac{\ln a}{a}$ will be cut precisely twice by $\frac{\ln x}{x}$.

This will be obvious to you if you sketch the graph.

**Negative solutions?**

Instead of taking $x$ to the power $a=1.6 +0.4k$ you could consider not $x^a$ but $(x^2)^{0.8+0.2k}.$

You now have a fractional power of a positive number and so you can happily equate this expression with $a^x$. But please note that this is not the same as solving your original equation.

(This is, I believe, why you were convinced that you had solutions which others were saying did not exist.)

Comment: I don't get why y = ln(a)/a cuts ln(x)/x 2 times, can you elaborate it please?, what I am thinking is ln(a)/a is a point and it shall cut the graph only once.
And for the negative solution, for every x,a > 1, there will be definitely a negative solution. (Just by graphing x^a and a^x)

Comment: Think of ln(a)/a as a number e.g. 2. Then we are finding where ln(x)/x cuts the **line** y=2.

Comment: Ah, Got it, Thanks !. But, according to you, wouldn't every value of a has 2 cuts?

Comment: P.S. Sort out your understanding of the positive solutions first and then, if necessary, I'll explain what the issue is re. negative solutions.

Comment: For a=e the curve just touches the line. For $a\le 1$ the line is below the x-axis and is only cut once. Of course all the values you are considering are not affected by this.

Comment: So what you are saying is, as long as a > 1 and a != e, we have 2 pos. solutions for x^a = a^x, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Ok so, all we have to see is why a = 1.6+0.4*k adds a negative solution,right?

Comment: Yes. However, there is a relatively complicated  issue with fractional powers of negative numbers. For example, while (-1)^n is fine for n an integer it is not real for n=1/2.

Comment: But a isn't negative fractional number, it is positive, so how does this complicate?

Comment: You are considering x to the power a where x is negative and some of the a are not integers.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for the clarification ! , So, there is no plausible explanation for negative solutions?

Comment: I will add a way of getting negative solutions to my solution - it will take a few minutes.

Comment: You haven't proved why there is a negative solution whenever a is 1.6+0.4*k, and yes, a negative solution does exist !

Answer (score 0):

Taking the logarithm on both sides we get
$$\frac{\ln(x)}{x}=\frac{\ln(a)}{a}$$ Now you can discover how many times cut $$\frac{\ln(a)}{a}$$ the graph of $$\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$

Comment: But ln(a)/a is a constant, so wouldn't it cut the graph at a single point?

Comment: You must consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$$ by calculus

Comment: Doesn't ln(a)/a being a constant cut the graph of f(x) at a single point?

Comment: $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ can cut $f(x)$ two times

Comment: how can a graph cut itself 2 times? what do you mean? Could you please clarify up a bit?Thanks,John.

Comment: Sorry i mean $$\frac{\ln(a)}{a}$$

Comment: If $x<0$, then $\log x$ is not well defined, therefore this argument does not give you the negative solutions, which are claimed to exist

Comment: @Krishnarjun, Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.

Let us say that $a\neq 1$ and also $x\neq 1$, then we are interested in finding $x$ such that $$\frac{a}{\log a}=\frac{x}{\log x}.$$ If you consider the given domain, (by plotting a graph using a computer), we can see that there are precisely two different values for $x$ which satisfy this equation. This takes care of the two positive solutions. The third solution, if it exists should therefore be negative.

Fix $a>0$. Suppose there is a negative solution, call it $-y$ where $y>0$. Therefore we have that $$(-y)^a=\frac{1}{a^y}\Rightarrow (-1)^a(y)^a=\frac{1}{a^y}\Rightarrow \left(\cos(a\pi)+i\sin(a\pi)\right)(y)^a=\frac{1}{a^y}.$$

Since the right hand side is a real number (since $a>0$ and $y>0$), we should have that $\sin(a\pi)=0$, that is $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore whenever $a$ is non integral, there does not exist three solutions. Furthermore when $a$ is odd, we will have $$- y^a = a^{-y}$$ which is not possible because the LHS is a negative number and the RHS is a positive number (Again since $a>0$ and $y>0$). Therefore for a negative solution to exist, $a$ has to be even. In this case we are interested in solving, $y^a = a^{-y}$, where once again the $\log$ trick can be used.

Comment: In order to explain the third negative root in the case of non integral values of $a$, I think it is necessary to consider $y^a$ and $a^y$ as complex numbers. I observed that for $a=3$, there are only two solutions. (Also your formula for $a$ will only give even integral values for $a$. It will not give odd integral values)

Comment: "Therefore whenever a is non integral, there does not exist three solutions". check by putting a = 1.6. And, I am just asking "Why are there 3 solutions whenever a is 1.6+0.4*k" , it doesn't matter if I don't include odd integral values of a, all I am asking is about this form. I don't know whether you have done wrong, but the conclusion is definitely not right.